# could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, faraday

I don't understand what's the problem here while installing gem. Here are the details of error log

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
faraday (= 0.12.1)

In Gemfile:
faraday

mailchimp3 (= 1.3.1) was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
  faraday (~> 0.9.1)

stripe was resolved to 2.10.0, which depends on
  faraday (~> 0.9)
```

FYI: I'm using rails 5, ruby 2.4.1.

Comment: Use newest version of stripe will solve your problem `gem 'stripe', '~> 3.9', '>= 3.9.1'`

Comment: Yeah it works fine